# Can't get DrawLine to work when triggered by a button press.

Tags: c#, graphics, event-handling

this code works just fine when it's in a different delegate, but doesn't work when it's triggered by a button.  "Draw_Click" is a button called "Draw" and it's supposed to make a drawing on the screen based on a pre-made array of points.

```
 private void Draw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics myInstance = this.CreateGraphics();

        for (int t = 0; t <= numberOfPoints - 1; t++)
        {
            myInstance.DrawLine(pen, spiroArray[0, t], spiroArray[1, t], spiroArray[0, t + 1], spiroArray[1, t + 1]);
        }

    }
```

But when I have this same code in this class, it works fine (minus the myInstance line).

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

I use "e" instead of "myInstance" just to make this question as brief as possible.

Basically, what's so special about Form1_Paint?  Shouldn't I be able to make it draw something even outside that special Form1Paint class?  If I use that Form1_Paint, I don't have control over when it does the drawing. I'm basically trying to have it update the drawing as the user changes parameters, etc.

The error is "Error 1   The name 'DrawLine' does not exist in the current context"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It has to do with the `this` specifier; it probably refers to the wrong context in the function. Try identifying the object by using its actual full name.

Comment: @Jean-Paul using `this` in Winforms is common, it refers to the form that the `Click()` event is raised on.

Comment: _what's so special about Form1_Paint_ Paint events are special, because they are what the system will call when __it__ needs to refresh the application. Minimize&maximize your programm and all your pixels are __gone__! So you need to do __all__ drawing in them or called from them , passing out the e.Graphics object to make the drawing persistent!

Comment: TaW, so then I have to have my button click call the Form1_Paint event then?  Thus I have to come up with a line of code in which a button click causes Form1_Paint to be called?  OK.  I need a moment to think about the right way to code that.

Comment: I don't know what to do.  This doesn't work:  Form1_Paint(sender, e);  when I put it into the Button_click delegate.  Also, when I press the clearScreen button, I think I'm going to run into the same problem, as I am unable to have a Paint event handled outside the Form1_Paint delegate.

Comment: Basically, what's working now is another method call.  I don't know why I couldn't just do something within the delegate, but doing it this way removes the need for "e.method".   private void Draw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            makeMyDrawing();
            
        }                                                                                                                   private void makeMyDrawing(){code goes here}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am getting your question correctly, because if I read your question and code the way I think, the error you should be getting is that "pen" does not exist in the current context.  If you use that same code to draw, it will work on either the button_click or the form_paint events.  "this" will still refer to the form, and using it to instantiate a graphics object will give you access to draw anywhere in the form.  From either the button click handler or the form paint method.  However, the only think I can see that would fail is if you never defined the pen.  Here is the code I used, and it drew a red line when the form first came up, and then drew a black line when I clicked on the button I had put on the same form.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics myInstance = this.CreateGraphics();
        myInstance.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 15, 10, 25, 20);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics myInstance = this.CreateGraphics();
        myInstance.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 20, 20);
    }
```

There has to be something that is not coming across right in the statement of your question.

Comment: I've made Pens a field, and thus it's class wide in scope.  So, I don't think that's it.

Comment: Don't know what else to tell you.  You said "I use 'e' instead of 'myInstance' just to make this question as brief as possible."  So I think I am not seeing the code that is actually giving you the error.  The code you show here, inside the draw_click event handler should work fine in either that handler or the form_paint handler.